# Problems uploading different file types in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Below is my script that i'm using to upload different files. All the solutions I've found deal only with multiple image uploads. I am totally stumped for a solution on this. Can someone tell me what it is i'm supposed to be doing to upload different files in the same form? Thanks

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/nav';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        return $error;
    }   
    else
    {

        $soundfig['upload_path'] = './uploads/nav';
        $soundfig['allowed_types'] = 'mp3|wav';

        $this->load->library('upload', $soundfig);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('soundfile'))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            return $error;
        }   
        else
        {

            $data = $this->upload->data('userfile');
            $sound = $this->upload->data('soundfile');
            $full_path = 'uploads/nav/' . $data['file_name'];
            $sound_path = 'uploads/nav/' . $sound['file_name'];

            if($this->input->post('active') == '1'){
                $active = '1';
            }else{
                $active = '0';
            }

            $spam = array(
                'image_url' => $full_path,
                'sound' => $sound_path,
                'active' => $active,
                'url' => $this->input->post('url')
            );

            $id = $this->input->post('id');

            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->update('NavItemData', $spam);

            return true;
        }       
    }
}
```

Here is my form:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
<?php if(isset($buttons)) : foreach($buttons as $row) : ?>
<h2><?php echo $row->name; ?></h2>
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" /><br />
<input type="file" name="soundfile" size="20" />
<input type="hidden" name="oldfile" value="<?php echo $row->image_url; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />

<br /><br />
<label>Url: </label><input type="text" name="url" value="<?php echo $row->url; ?>" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="active" value="1" <?php if($row->active == '1') { echo 'checked'; } ?> /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `$config['allowed_types']` line from your code if you want to upload all types of files or use that array to specify the file types you would like to upload eg:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|etc';
```

Comment: i would like to keep the validation in place as users tend to be idiots! is there not someway of using two different configs at once? cheers though :)

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you:-

```
        <select name="file_provider2">
            <option value="singa">Singapore</option>
        </select> 
          <input type="file" name="singafile" id="singafile">

        <select name="file_provider1">
            <option value="usa">USA</option>
        </select> 
          <input type="file" name="usafile" id="usafile">
```

Controller:-

```
if($this->input->post("file_provider1")=="usa"){
                if ($_FILES['usafile']['size'] > 0){
                 $file = $_FILES['usafile']['tmp_name'];  
               //all code goes here for first file
   }
}
if($this->input->post("file_provider2")=="singa"){
                if ($_FILES['usafile']['size'] > 0){
                $file = $_FILES['singafile']['tmp_name']; 
               //all code goes here for 2nd file
   }
}
```